# Relation with Generalized Eigenvectors/Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*Claim:* Let $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of index $m \geq 2$ and a corresponding eigenvector $v_{1}$. Let $v_{2}$ be a generalized eigenvector such that $(A - \lambda I)v_{2} = v_{1}$. Show that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$ A^{n}v_{2} = \lambda^{n}v_{2} + n\lambda^{n-1}v_{1}$$

Any hints on where to start?

Comment: Mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Rewrite the equality that characterises $v_2$ as:
$$Av_2=\lambda v_2+v_1$$
This is the initial step. Then apply $A$ to both sides. and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.